# react-native-video TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

Tags: javascript, react-native, video-player, react-native-video

I am trying to implement video element in my react native app. I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constants' of null

This error is located at:
    in Video (at VideoScreen.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at VideoScreen.js:48)
    in VideoScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:555)
    in Dummy (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:498)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at CompatNativeSafeAreaProvider.tsx:28)
    in CompatNativeSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:13)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:12)
    in Soap2Day (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.windows.js:52)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
```

Here's my video element:

```
<Video
    resizeMode="contain"
    source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
    style={styles.videoPlayer} />
```

The code works perfeectly on android, but on windows it doesn't. I have tried recompiling the windows app without success. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/1820). I think you are not linking `react-native-video` correctly for windows.

Comment: On `react-native-video` github it says that Autolinking should automatically add `react-native-video` to my app.

Comment: Yeah but autolinking sometimes has errors, I would double check Windows steps and be sure its correct. Also double check that you are not missing a required property for windows for this Video component.

Comment: I have tried to link my app manually, but not the app just crashes without an error.

Comment: same here. i'm trying but not working

Comment: @KarloA.López Thanks. I just reran npx react-native-asset again and it works, never had this issue before though.

Comment: any update on how to fix this?